# Grails upload file no signature for method getFile()

Tags: grails, file-upload

I am implementing simple form with input fields and file upload.
I went over tutorial: http://grails.org/Simple+Avatar+Uploader
and documentation: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles

However file upload doesn't seem to work!
Why is it not working? Any solutions for the problem?

Issue:

> No signature of method:
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
>   [itemImage] Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String),
>   getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(),
>   getJSON(). Stacktrace follows: Message: No signature of method:
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
>   [itemImage] Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String),
>   getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(),
>   getJSON()    Line | Method
>   ->>  14 | save     in greatoffer.SellController$$EOVmPG4d
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  |   195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter |    63 |
>   doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter |    53 |
>   doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
>   |    49 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
>   |    82 | doFilter in
>   grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
>   |   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker |
>   918 | run      in     '' ^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

Main GSP:

```
<g:uploadForm action="save" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:uploadForm>
```

Image Upload part of the Form GSP:

```
<label for="images">
    <g:message code="item.images.label" default="Images" />
</label>

<input type="file" name="itemImage" />
```

Controller:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured('permitAll')
class SellController {

    def index() {
        render(view: "seller")
    }

    def save() {
        println "Here are params: ${params}";
        def f = request.getFile('itemImage')
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'item.label', default: 'Item'), params.id])
        render(view: "seller")
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet that it will work without the @Secured('permitAll') annotation.

Comment: Guessing @lukelazarovic may be on to something - because the getFile method is part of the MultipartRequest  but maybe not the part of the security.  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartRequest.html#getFile(java.lang.String)  not in this class which appears to be the class for the request  http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the type in your stack trace, the Spring Security @Secured annotation is wrapping your request in a [SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.html). You need to get at the [MultipartHttpServletRequest](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartHttpServletRequest.html) to call getFile I believe.

Also, in your debug Here are params statement, are you seeing the itemImage? If so, I actually think it might be this easy.

```
def file = params.itemImage
```

UPDATE: I upvoted the comments.  They weren't there when I started typing.

Comment: Thanks dude! Also I reviewed all of the code again and I got to admit that I am idiot and made a mistake - modified wrong GSP page.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Do you have any hint on how to get at the MultipartHttpServletRequest from a SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper?