# How do I get a MultipartRequest out of a Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper

Tags: grails, upload, spring-security

I'm using Grails 2.4.3 and I have a `<g:uploadForm>` with method set to post, but I'm not getting a **MutlipartRequest** in my controller action.  Instead I'm getting a **Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper** which has not `getFile()` method.  I've tried casting, I've tried getting the request out of the wrapper with `request.request`, and I've tried a bunch of other things I've seen suggested to others with a similar problem, but still no dice.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.  I tend to do that, but if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

Here's my form:

```
  <g:uploadForm method="POST" action="uploadSupplemental" >
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Upload Supplemental Data File</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <label for="fileInput">Choose file to upload:</label>
      <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="supplementalData" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
  </g:uploadForm>
```

And here's my controller action:

```
  def uploadSupplemental() {
    MultipartRequest multipartRequest =  request as MultipartRequest
    def file = multipartRequest.getFile('supplementalData')
    if (file){
      flash.message = "File found!!"
    } else {
      flash.message = "File NOT found.  :-( "
    }
    redirect action:'list'
  }
```

And here's the error I get:

> URI /app/upload/uploadSupplemental Class
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException Message No signature of method:
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
>   [supplementalData] Possible solutions: getXML(),
>   getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String),
>   getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getJSON()

Comment: Some more info: The first time I access the request, inside my controller action, the request is of type: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.  If I call getRequest() on that, I get a org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$Servlet3SaveToSessionRequestWrapper. Still a wrapper, so I call getRequest on that and get a org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper, another wrapper.   (continued...)

Comment: One more call to org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestWrapper.getRequest gives me a org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.  So I finally have a request object, but it's not the MultipartRequest that it's supposed to be.  Still stumped.

Comment: What is the value of the `grails.web.disable.multipart` set to in `Config.groovy`? Here is a related [JIRA issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-191) and a [duplicate question in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764419/grails-upload-file-no-signature-for-method-getfile) reporting the same exception. Also make sure the user is authenticated before the upload action. It is sure that `@Secured` is used in controller.

Comment: @dmahapatro, That did the trick. Thanks!  Can you put this into an answer?

Comment: Done. Glad that digging was helpful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following config property has to be set to `true` in `Config.groovy` in order to enable multipart requests.

```
grails.web.disable.multipart=true
```

Here is a [related JIRA issue](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-191) and [a duplicate question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764419/grails-upload-file-no-signature-for-method-getfile) reporting the same exception.

Also make sure the user is authenticated (with `@Secured`) before the upload action.

Comment: this solution does not work for me, but i dont have the secured annotaion but i also get HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper. An idea how to solve this?
Note: The upload works on desktop but not on mobile

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error in my grails application and came up with the following solution:

The type of the request instance in my app was related to the content-type attribute inside the HTTP post that reaches the server. So, if I had a file input inside a form with enctype attribute set like...

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload" method="POST">
```

... I got a MutlipartRequest as expected and could get the uploaded file calling `request.getFile()`.

But if the HTTP post had a content-type of "application/octet-stream" (as when we use Valum's AJAX File-Uploader to upload a single file), than the request is, itself, a binary file and can be converted to an InputStream by calling `request.getInputStream()`.

So, if you're not sure what content-type is being used in your app, I recommend checking it with a browser tool like firebug and trying `request.getInputStream()` to get the file straight from the request.

[See the diference between content-type and enctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339770/whats-the-difference-between-content-type-and-enctype)