# Difficulty with uploading video files to a web app

Tags: grails, upload, spring-security

I building a web app using Grails 2.3.8 I have a feature where I can upload videos so I can later download them. Before we implemented the spring security both the download and upload feature were working. After implementation attempting to upload a video gives this error.

```
No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [mp4Name] Possible solutions: getXML(), getPart(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(java.lang.String), getLocale(), getJSON()
```

I took a look at this link and tried what it said but I keep getting the same error. [How do I get a MultipartRequest out of a Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736028/how-do-i-get-a-multipartrequest-out-of-a-servlet3securitycontextholderawarereque)

This is my form code

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: videoInstance, field: 'fileName', 'error')} required">
<label for="fileName">
    <g:message code="video.fileName.label" default="Video Name" />
    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:textField name="fileName" required="" value="${videoInstance?.fileName}"/>
```

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: videoInstance, field: 'mp4File', 'error')} required">
<label for="mp4NameT">
    <g:message code="video.videoPath.mp4.label" default="Mp4 Path" />
    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</label>
<g:textField name="mp4NameT" required="" value="${videoInstance?.mp4File}" readonly=""/>
<input type="file" id="mp4Name" name="mp4Name">
```

The above is the same for four more video file types. f4v, mov, 3gp, and 3gp light.
and this is the section that has my save method for videos

```
@Transactional
def save() {

    def videoInstance = new Video()
    bindData(videoInstance, params, [exclude: ['mp4File']])
    videoInstance.properties = params

    if (videoInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    def dest = new File('web-app/videos')
    def destOut = "/videos"
    if(!dest.exists()) dest.mkdirs()
    videoInstance.validate()


    MultipartRequest multipartRequest = request as MultipartRequest

    MultipartFile mp4F= multipartRequest.getFile('mp4Name')
    MultipartFile f4vF= multipartRequest.getFile('f4vName')
    MultipartFile movF= multipartRequest.getFile('movName')
    MultipartFile gpF = multipartRequest.getFile('gpName')
    MultipartFile lightF=multipartRequest.getFile('lightName')


    if (mp4F.empty||f4vF.empty||movF.empty||gpF.empty||lightF.empty) {
        println 'empty'
        flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
        render(view:'_form')
    }
    else{
        println 'not empty'
        def mp4Namer=params.fileName+'.mp4'
        def f4vNamer=params.fileName+'.f4v'
        def movNamer=params.fileName+'.mov'
        def gpNamer =params.fileName+'.3gp'
        def lightNamer=params.fileName+'_Light.3gp'

        videoInstance.mp4File=''+'web-app/videos/'+mp4Namer
        mp4F.transferTo( new File('web-app/videos/'+mp4Namer))

        videoInstance.f4vFile=''+'web-app/videos/'+f4vNamer
        f4vF.transferTo( new File('web-app/videos/'+f4vNamer))

        videoInstance.movFile=''+'web-app/videos/'+movNamer
        movF.transferTo( new File('web-app/videos/'+movNamer))

        videoInstance.gpFile=''+'web-app/videos/'+gpNamer
        gpF.transferTo( new File('web-app/videos/'+gpNamer))

        videoInstance.lightFile=''+'web-app/videos/'+lightNamer
        lightF.transferTo( new File('web-app/videos/'+lightNamer))


    }
    videoInstance.validate()
    if (videoInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond videoInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }

    videoInstance.save flush:true

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'video.label', default: 'Video'), videoInstance.title])
            redirect videoInstance
        }
        '*' { respond videoInstance, [status: CREATED] }
    }
}
```

I have set the `grails.web.disable.multipart` to true
is there something simple that I am missing to make that method work.

Comment: Did you use a g:form or a g:uploadForm ?