# Upload from mobile an image in java with ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, grails

First of all, I don't use jQueryMobile.
I want to upload an image on a tomcat7 server.
In desktop-app it works fine, but when im going mobile, it will cause an error:

> No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.getFile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [file]

This is my java-code:

```
// get the file to upload
def uploadFileInput = 'file'
MultipartFile sourceFile = request.getFile(uploadFileInput)
```

this is my ajax:

```
$.ajax( {
    url        : createLink( {controller: 'fileManager', action: 'upload', id: Location.params.id, params: {domain: Location.controller, profile: true}} ),
    data       : new FormData( form[0] ),
    cache      : false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success    : function( data ) {
        [...]
    },
    error      : function() {
        console.log( 'Upload canceled with errors' )
   }
} );
```

this is my html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" accept="jpg,png,gif" style="display: none">
</form>
```

Did I forget something?

Comment: it should NOT work that way at all, as the form does not contain the file content

Comment: file content? what do you mean?

Comment: `new FormData( form[0] )` doesn't deliver the file to be processed by `request.getFile( 'file' )`. You will get nothing

Comment: but on desktop I get a file... anyway.. what should I use instead?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "desktop", but there the file seems to be included into the request, what the `$.ajax()` is NOT doing

Comment: desktop is normal computer... desktop -> computer .. mobile -> mobilephone, android, ios..  on desktop and mobile im using same functions so what you see here is for desktop and mobile

Comment: is you issue solved yet ??

Comment: No. I still have the problem and no answer

Comment: Can you please check this if it helps  ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764419/grails-upload-file-no-signature-for-method-getfile
 
and this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736028/how-do-i-get-a-multipartrequest-out-of-a-servlet3securitycontextholderawarereque

Comment: I need a multipart file and params.file is not filled